# Change rotate animation position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement rotate animation its working but I want to change the div position. Here is my code:-

```
$(function(){
var el=$('div');
el.animate({ deg: 180 }, {
            duration: 1000,
            step: function (now) {
                el.css({
                    transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'
                });
            },
            complete: function () {                    
     },
  });
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PU3sJ/50/)

I want this position(now its first but I want second):-

[image]

Thanks for your hepl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `translateY(-100%)`

```
$(function(){
var el=$('div');
 el.animate({ deg: 180 }, {
                duration: 1000,
                step: function (now) {
                    el.css({
                        transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg) translateY(-100%)'
                    });
                },
                complete: function () {

         },
   });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/51bzbsmc/)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(function(){
    var el=$('div');
var topik = $('div').css('top');
    el.animate({ deg: 180 }, {
                duration: 1000,
                step: function (now) {
                    el.css({
                        transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)',
                        top : topik+'500px',
    });
                },
                complete: function () {                    
         },
      });
    })
```

Dont thank me ;););)

Comment: i am so sorry my friend :(